# Use $addToSet with Spring Batch MongoItemWriter

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-batch, mongotemplate

I'm currently implementing a Spring Batch application with a *MongoItemWriter*, and I need to add some logic in the mongo upsert query, like adding a field in an array only if it does not exist (*$addToSet* if I'm not mistaken).

My first idea was to override the *MongoItemWriter* to change the *saveOrUpdate* method behavior while keeping the benefits of the existing spring batch bulk configuration. But all this part is private and so I have to rewrite all if I want to change the mongo query.

Another solution could be to implement the addToSet logic in the processor with a find, but it seems not optimized (one find query by item).

It is very strange that Spring Batch does not allow to configure easily the mongo query (that offers a lot of possibility) while keeping the existing transaction and bulk configuration.

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: I am not sure what Spring Batch is, but in my experience SpringData repositories offer very little control.  Try to use the SpringData templates instead, they offer more driver related offerings.  By the way, any Spring method that has the word "Save" in the name is likely going to be poor performing, as the framework results in wholesale updates instead of targeted updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `doWrite`  and `getTemplate` methods are protected, so you can override `doWrite` and use the template as needed (without having to deal with item buffering or transaction management which are handled in the `write` method).

With that, you should have full control over item writing and you can create/customize the query as needed. That said, if you think other methods could be opened for extension, please open a feature request and we can discuss how to improve the extensibility of the writer.